# How to process the sub dataframe in parallel in pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark

```
df = pd.read_csv("imeis_events_march.csv")
imeis = df['imei'].unique().tolist()
for imei in imeis:
    dfj = df.loc[df['imei']==imei]
    # calculate feature
    props = calculate_ratio(dfj)
```

I want to use the `calculate_ratio` function to process each sub dataframe in an efficient way.
Is there any good approach to implement this in parallel ?
The desiring result would be

> imei:props

for each imei.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PySpark dataframe, [group](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) it by `imei` and then use [applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) to process each group as a separate *Pandas* dataframe in parallel:

```
pdf = pd.read_csv("imeis_events_march.csv")
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

def calculate_ratio(pandas_df):
    pandas_df['ratio'] = 1.0 #implement the real logic here
    return pandas_df

schema_with_ratio = "imei string, ...other columns..., ratio float"

df.groupBy("imei").applyInPandas(calculate_ratio, schema_with_ratio).show()
```

`calculate_ratio` will be called by Spark with a *Pandas* dataframe once for each `imei` in the input data.

A downside of this approach is that each group of `imei`s has to fit completey into the memory of one of the Spark executors or an OutOfMemory error will occur.